# moving background in box2d game

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

ok so im trying to find some tutorials on how to create a moving background for a box2d game. it my first time doing it, and i dont know what they are called? can anyone tell me what they are called so i can search for some tutorials on it..

heres what im trying to do.. firstly my game is in portrait mode, and i have created an image which is 960x320 and i want it to continually run as the background of the game.... like a road which goes on forever..

can someone tell me what i can search on google to find a good tutorial for accomplish this? thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the tutorial of the CCParallaxScrollNode by which you can do the endless scrolling of the Background. I dont know the exact link but you need to download the 4 files they are

1. CCParallaxScrollNode.h
2. CCParallaxScrollNode.mm
3. CCParallaxScrollOffset.h
4. CCParallaxScrollOffset.mm

Now in your test demo implement the below code

in your  .h file code is

```
    CCParallaxScrollNode *parlax;
    CCParallaxNode* paraNode;
```

in .mm file you need to declare before @implementation set

```
float myVelocity = -4;
```

the below code in init method

```
CCSprite *clouds1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
CCSprite *clouds2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
parlax= [CCParallaxScrollNode node];
[parlax addInfiniteScrollYWithZ:0 Ratio:ccp(0.5,0.5) Pos:ccp(0,0) Objects:clouds1,clouds2,nil];

[self addChild:parlax z:-1];
[self scheduleUpdate];

-(void) update : (ccTime) dt
{
    [parlax updateWithVelocity:ccp(0,myVelocity) AndDelta:dt];
}
```

The sprites can be replaced with your own sprites also you can do some modification for the Landscape also. The code is for the portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourite sites for cocos2D tutorials is [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/).
You'll find loads of cocos2d material there.

Comment: +1  For a question as broad as this, pointing someone to this site is probably the best course of action.  I'll forgive your backward way of spelling favorite ;-)